# Using Plotly latest version and getting error : module 'plotly.validators.layout' has no attribute 'ExtendtreemapcolorsValidator'

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am writing a code for making a graph and using the latest plotly version. Previously it wasn't working so **I had to downgrade to 3.4.10 version of Plotly** . Still getting this error. Any suggestions would be helpful. TIA!!

`choromap = go.Figure(data=[data],layout =layout)`

Used this command for running one of my programs and got this as an error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-5fb62f726a1c> in <module>
----> 1 choromap = go.Figure(data=[data],layout =layout)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/_figure.py in __init__(self, data, layout, frames, skip_invalid, **kwargs)
    606             is invalid AND skip_invalid is False
    607         """
--> 608         super(Figure, self).__init__(data, layout, frames, skip_invalid, **kwargs)
    609 
    610     def add_area(

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in __init__(self, data, layout_plotly, frames, skip_invalid, **kwargs)
    197         # ### Import Layout ###
    198         self._layout_obj = self._layout_validator.validate_coerce(
--> 199             layout, skip_invalid=skip_invalid
    200         )
    201 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_plotly_utils/basevalidators.py in validate_coerce(self, v, skip_invalid)
   2442 
   2443         elif isinstance(v, dict):
-> 2444             v = self.data_class(v, skip_invalid=skip_invalid)
   2445 
   2446         elif isinstance(v, self.data_class):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/__init__.py in __init__(self, arg, angularaxis, annotations, annotationdefaults, autosize, bargap, bargroupgap, barmode, barnorm, boxgap, boxgroupgap, boxmode, calendar, clickmode, coloraxis, colorscale, colorway, datarevision, direction, dragmode, editrevision, extendfunnelareacolors, extendpiecolors, extendsunburstcolors, extendtreemapcolors, font, funnelareacolorway, funnelgap, funnelgroupgap, funnelmode, geo, grid, height, hiddenlabels, hiddenlabelssrc, hidesources, hoverdistance, hoverlabel, hovermode, images, imagedefaults, legend, mapbox, margin, meta, metasrc, modebar, orientation, paper_bgcolor, piecolorway, plot_bgcolor, polar, radialaxis, scene, selectdirection, selectionrevision, separators, shapes, shapedefaults, showlegend, sliders, sliderdefaults, spikedistance, sunburstcolorway, template, ternary, title, titlefont, transition, treemapcolorway, uirevision, updatemenus, updatemenudefaults, violingap, violingroupgap, violinmode, waterfallgap, waterfallgroupgap, waterfallmode, width, xaxis, yaxis, **kwargs)
  97544         self._validators[
  97545             "extendtreemapcolors"
> 97546         ] = v_layout.ExtendtreemapcolorsValidator()
  97547         self._validators["font"] = v_layout.FontValidator()
  97548         self._validators["funnelareacolorway"] = v_layout.FunnelareacolorwayValidator()

AttributeError: module 'plotly.validators.layout' has no attribute 'ExtendtreemapcolorsValidator'
```

Comment: Do you mind to share a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install a new package `chart-studio`. In your command line type and run:

```
pip install chart-studio
```

Then make sure you import it by running the code:

```
import chart_studio.plotly as py
```